# Error message when trying to run PIP

Tags: python, pip, moviepy

When I try to install moviepy with:

```
sudo pip install moviepy
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==6.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 552, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2672, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2345, in load
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2351, in resolve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 92, in load_module
    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'
```

I'm a total novice at programming and have no idea what that means.

Here's what pops up when I type in "which pip":

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

So it seems like I have pip....

I'm in way over my head. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: installing with sudo inside `/usr/local/` will mess up everything. Don't do that. You can see if `pip install --upgrade setuptools` works.

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/22816 - this issue (though for Mac) looks very similar (solution was https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/22816#issuecomment-39017095)